# Adding one more row to existing excel file in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel

I am trying to simply add one more row to an existing excel file using [spreadsheet](http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/GUIDE_txt.html) gem.

```
test_url = "#{Rails.root}/data/Skipped_Records.xls"

if File.exists?(test_url)
    book = Spreadsheet.open(test_url)
else 
    book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
    book.create_worksheet
end

sheet = book.worksheet(0)
last_index = sheet.row(-1).idx
sheet.row(last_index + 1).concat [index, error] 
book.write "#{Rails.root}/data/Skipped_Records.xls"
```

In first run the file is getting created fine.
But after second run, while opening the file LibreOffice says

```
Unknown or unsupported excel file format.
```

I am trying to migrate excel data into rails application using rake task. While doing it few rows are skipped because of certain errors. I am trying to log these skipped records.

Please help.

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure but it seems like `spreadsheet` gem doesn't allow to insert something in existed xls. You should use it only for creating new xls.

Comment: Yes, I also could not find any where how to insert new row. I think it only allows to modify existing rows as mentioned here http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/GUIDE_txt.html